# how can i get value from response header | API | CURL

Tags: php, api

I have integration with other servers using API
but I can not get value from the response header to complete authentication and get the session of the server

I try this code

```
$init = curl_init();

$Auth = [];

$response_headers = [];

$header_callback = function($init,$Auth) use (&$response_headers){
    $len = strlen($Auth);

    $response_headers[] = $Auth;

    return $len;
};

curl_setopt_array($init, [
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://ip-api/v1/rest/auth',
    CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
    CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION => $header_callback
    
]);

$output = curl_exec($init);

$info = curl_getinfo($init);

var_dump($Auth);

echo $Auth[0];

curl_close($init);
```

but the result is

> Warning: Undefined array key 0 in //path

how can get this value
[image]

Comment: `$len = strlen($AuthNonce);` - where is `$AuthNonce` supposed to come from, that does not exist within the scope of your function.

Comment: `$AuthNonce =  $_GET['AuthNonce'];` - did you actually call the script with such a GET parameter? From your Postman screenshot, it doesn't look like it.

Comment: $Auth-Nonce is dynamic value not static value  when i get a request and it's came from response header

Comment: Ok. But as pointed out...it doesn't exist in your callback function. Where are you expecting it to come from?

Comment: P.S. Instead of `echo $Auth['AuthNonce'];` try `var_dump($Auth);` so you can see what's actually in the variable, and work out what you can or cannot read from it. I don't see any evidence that you've tried to debug this code. From the PostMan screenshot, it seems that the header returned is named `Auth-Nonce` not `AuthNonce`

Comment: i try $Auth = ['Auth-Nonce'];   and  var_dump($Auth);   and i  get    array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "Auth-Nonce" also i see all response header value as postman

Comment: `$Auth = ['Auth-Nonce'];`...this is gibberish and seemingly pure guesswork which suggests you don't really understand PHP syntax properly.

Comment: `var_dump($Auth); and i get array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "Auth-Nonce"`...there's your clue then. The array is numerically indexed. Try writing `echo $Auth[0];`. Was there anything else in that dump output? You can [edit] your question to show us the whole thing.

Comment: var_dump($Auth);   i get array(0) { }     echo $Auth[0];   i get Warning: Undefined array key 0 in //path

Comment: `var_dump($Auth); i get array(0) { } `...that's not what you said before. Make up your mind. Or did you change something in the code? Or maybe the curl request failed for some reason? It's very difficult to tell what's going on when you just post small things out of context, with no explanation. Again, [edit] your question to make it clearer, then everything is coherent and in one place, and you have space to write a proper explanation

Comment: i'm sorry Mr adyson i edit my question

Comment: Ok thanks. I think you should be writing `var_dump($response_headers);` actually. You are never adding any values to `$Auth`  (or at least, not the instance of it which is outside the callback).

Comment: i get it i get it   Mr adyson thank you so much from the earth to the moon

Comment: var_dump($response_headers);
echo $response_headers [11]; and i get value thank you for your patience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you need is within `$response_headers`, not `$Auth`.

e.g.

```
echo $response_headers [11];
```

would get you the specific value.

Comment: i have question Mr ADyson if i need this value $response_headers[11] to get another value $auth1 using this arithmetic function   $auth1= ( (doubleval(doubleval ($response_headers[11]) / 13) % 99999) * 17 );
 echo number_format($auth1, 0, '.', '');  how ?

Comment: Wel, what problem occurs when you try to do that?

Comment: the result is 0

Comment: Using the sample auth-nonce value from your screenshot, I get 669477 - demo: https://3v4l.org/42maX . I'm not sure what value you're testing with, obviously. It wasn't clear if `$response_headers[11]` contains just the integer value, or actually a key-value pair of the header. I've assumed the former in my test, but that may not be the case - you can check that (I can't, because I can't run your curl request)

Comment: exactly you are right  the $response_headers[11]   contains integer value and key-value  so how can i get only integer value without key-value?

Comment: Show me precisely what it contains, please, from when you echo it

Comment: echo $response_headers[11];  the result is Auth-Nonce: 427275159 var_dump($response_headers[11]);  the result is string(23) "Auth-Nonce: 279748597 "

Comment: OK so you can split the string on the `:` to separate the value

Comment: i try this $part = explode(":",$response_headers[11]);

print_r($part); the result is Array ( [0] => Auth-Nonce [1] => 1275805786 )

Comment: OK. So just use the second item in your calculation. What's stopping you?

Comment: thank you Mr Adyson i got it sorry for your disturb

Comment: sorry Mr Adyson but may I please ask you just one last thing?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75418429/how-can-i-send-multi-url-using-curl-in-php

Answer (score -1):

You are looking this php function, if I understand right `apache_request_headers()`.

If you have apache this will work. An you will get an array with your headers  that you can loop over and take the `['Auth-Nonce']` key. If apache doesn't have the `$header['Auth-Nonce']` in the specific HTTP call, `null` will be returned.

```
$headers = apache_request_headers();
echo $header['Auth-Nonce'];
```

In case of Nginx and other webservers try this `getallheaders()`. If you get an error that says the function doesn't exist do it custom like this:

```
if (!function_exists('getallheaders'))  {
    function getallheaders()
    {
        if (!is_array($_SERVER)) {
            return array();
        }

        $headers = array();
        foreach ($_SERVER as $name => $value) {
            if (substr($name, 0, 5) == 'HTTP_') {
                $headers[str_replace(' ', '-', ucwords(strtolower(str_replace('_', ' ', substr($name, 5)))))] = $value;
            }
        }
        return $headers;
    }
}
```

In any case you will get your webserver headers on your call.

Comment: No, the OP is trying to get the response headers from the curl request they're making

Comment: Then just add `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);` on cURL create and then `$header = substr($response, 0, $header_size);` from your responce.  This is documented on documentation https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php#80442

Comment: That gets _all_ the headers as a string, not just a specific one (as per the OP's question). OP is using the callback function provided by php/curl which returns one header at a time. They are then putting each one into a separate array entry. The problem they had was simply misunderstanding which variable to read the results from. Look at the other comments and answers, because it seems you've misunderstood the question.